# Looping a merge for a amount of csv files using pandas

Tags: python, loops, csv, merge, pandas

Right now I'm creating a program which combines csv files into one with like columns not duplicated. The columns created would need to be added next the the adjacent column.

As of right now I'm able to get the files but I'm unable to determine a way to develop a way to iterate a data frame over each read csv and then merge all of these data frames together and push out a csv file.
RIght now I'm testing out this with three csv files with a common ID column
What I have right now is as follows:

```
        os.chdir(filedname)
        data = pd.merge([pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file) for
              file in glob.glob("*.csv")],on='ID')
        data.to_csv('merged.csv')
```

The files look like this:

```
(File 1)  (File 2)
ID  BLA   ID  X   
1   2     1   55
2   3     2   2
3   4     3   12
4   5     4   52
```

And each different column besides the ID column in each csv file in the directory should be merged with each other to create one csv file like this:

```
ID BLA X
1  2   55
2  3   2
3  4   12
4  5   52
```

Any advice would be great in helping me solve this problem.

Comment: do you have some tiny example? For example, if I have 2 csv's with column 'B', but the data in this columns are different, what do you want to get in column 'B' for resulting DataFrame?

Comment: I added some extra info and an example! Sorry about that.

Comment: ID's are different in two files, so do you want to join on ID or just add new columns without looking at ID column at all?

Comment: Oy vey, sorry again, I edited to make the ID the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple example:

```
# Demo DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,1,3]], columns=['ID','BLA','X'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,5,4],[3,10,100]], columns=['ID','X','BLA'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,8,7],[3,0,0]], columns=['ID','BLA','D'])

# Demo DataFrames sequence
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]

# Merge DataFrames
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID'])
for d in dfs:
    cols = [x for x in d.columns if x not in df.columns or x == 'ID']
    df = pd.merge(df, d[cols], on='ID', how='outer', suffixes=['',''])

# result
   ID  BLA  X  D
0   1    2  3  3
1   2    3  4  7
2   3    1  3  0
```

in your case it could be something like:

```
data = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f) for f in glob.glob("*.csv")]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID'])
for d in data:
    cols = [x for x in d.columns if x not in df.columns or x == 'ID']
    df = pd.merge(df, d[cols], on='ID', how='outer', suffixes=['',''])
```

Comment: I wanted to create a loop so it would add the columns from each CSV file located in a given directory to one main "merged" CSV. Does that help?

Comment: My output is the first csv file

(File 1)  
ID  BLA   
1   2    
2   3    
3   4     
4   5

Comment: I also get this error
AssertionError: cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block [FloatBlock: [ID, NCELLS, AREA, MEAN, STD, NCELLS_, AREA_, MEAN_, STD_, AREA_, MEAN_, STD_], 12 x 756, dtype float64] with duplicate items [Index([u'ID', u'NCELLS', u'AREA', u'MEAN', u'STD', u'NCELLS_', u'AREA_', u'MEAN_', u'STD_', u'NCELLS_', u'AREA_', u'MEAN_', u'STD_'], dtype=object)] does not have _ref_locs set

Comment: @user2986038 changed again